# no such file or directory at share folder

Tags: windows, bash, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtualenvwrapper

When I start bash, the following description appears:

```
-bash: /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh: No such file or directory

-bash: /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh: No such file or directory
```

i'm using Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux, with ubuntu distro.

I already tried uninstalling by `powershell pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper` or in bash `sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper`.

I also entered the share directory to delete the virtualenvwrapper folder, but it does not appear. I'm pressing LS and the folder does not appear.

I am also trying "`which virtualenvwrapper`" or "`which virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`" but this simply returns the same folder as I am.
i just need help to remove that message of bash

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/893448/bash-shell-error-no-such-file-or-directory/1049989

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there is a reference (potentially with `source` or `.`) to virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh in one of bash startup files. Look at the usual suspects: ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bash.rc, /etc/.bash_login

To help with debugging, consider getting by adding `set -x` to ~/.bashrc, or by running interactive session

```
bash -ix /dev/null
```

UPDATE, based on log:

Per https://superuser.com/questions/893448/bash-shell-error-no-such-file-or-directory/1049989

> I just had the same problem on Linux Mint.
>
> The following file was causing the issue:
>   /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
>
> I made a backup (just in case) and deleted it, and everything seems to
>   be working fine now.

Comment: Look like your system was configured (via /etc/bash.bashrc) to use virtualdevwrapper, and the product was removed from your system. See proposed solution in answer, Consider reinstall and uninstalling using `sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper` if this does not work

Comment: Have you tried removing : /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper. It worked for other users (see link)

Comment: i found the file at /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper.
i tried remove typing "rm -r virtualenvwrapper"  but:
rm: remove write-protected regular file 'virtualenvwrapper'? >> yes
rm: cannot remove 'virtualenvwrapper': Permission denied

Comment: perfect! i got it! I entered the folder /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper and i did it: https://superuser.com/a/1175404/1109227